# is using fs in the nuxt page safe?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, fs, server-side-rendering, head

I have a piece of code like below used on few pages. I need to create head section on server side to have structured data for google which can be different on different site.

```
head() {
if(process.server)
{
  var json= {}
  var fs = require('fs')
  var file = fs.readFileSync('static/headContent.json', 'utf-8')
  json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(file))
```

the purpose of this is to have posibility to ammned structured data for google without the need of another build.
I don't have any file server or api that would serve those files so I've found solution using direct access to file system. It works but I've heard this approach using fs to grab a file can be unsafe.  I couldn't find definite answer for this though. I'll appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: How many blocking filereads are needed to stop your application. Also i think you can require json files

Comment: unfortunately uisng require doesnt work in order to have dynamic content. when the file is changind I need to build again to see new stuff in head section.